# Wiremock - Autoconfigure doesn't load stubs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stub, wiremock

My wiremock doesn't seem to work with autoconfigure. I have json files in a folder named stubs in the classpath and I ran the standalone jar on the port 8080.

```
@AutoConfigureWireMock(stubs="classpath:/stubs", port = 0)
public class TestResource {

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        assertThat(this.service.go()).isEqualTo("Hello World!");
    }

}
```

Example of a json file

```
{
  "request" : {
    "url" : "/api/users",
    "method" : "GET",
    "bodyPatterns" : [ {
      "contains" : "some soap body"
    }]
  },
  "response" : {
    "status" : 200,
    "body" : "Hello World",
    "headers" : {
      "X-Application-Context" : "application:-1",
      "Content-Type" : "text/plain"
    }
  }
}
```

When I launch a request with GET -> localhost:8080/api/users/ It doesn't match with the json file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @AutoConfigureWireMock has default port of 8080, Try to not specify it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply added all my json with a POST request on localhost:8080/__admin/mappings/import
http://wiremock.org/docs/stubbing/